# After running paster, I have a few eggs in my product

Tags: plone, egg, paster

I just ran

`bin/paster create -t dexterity my.example`

After running it, I have the following:

```
 bootstrap.py
 docs
 my.example.egg-info
 PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.6.egg
 plone.cfg
 setup.cfg
 buildout.cfg
 my
 Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.6.egg
 PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg
 README.txt
 setup.py
```

Why do I also have 3 eggs? Is my buildout configured wrong?

I had just installed Plone4 with the unified installer and when I tried running the pater command I got this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NoDefault'
```

That's when I appended the `[paster]` portion to my buildout as shown [here](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/paste.html). Initially, my buildout only had the `[zopskel]` portion without the `[paster]` portion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is entirely normal, if somewhat irritating. Your setup.py file pulls these in with the `setup_requires` and `paster_plugins` sections:

```py
setup(...
    setup_requires=["PasteScript"],
    paster_plugins=["ZopeSkel"],
    ...
)
```

The ZopeSkel paster recipes use these eggs to let you add snippets to your generated egg at a later date. Remove the above two entries and the eggs if you do not need this feature.

Comment: oh, ok. glad to know that that was what was supposed to happen. Thanks for also clarifying why and what to do :-)